# Proving an interesting basic inequality

Tags: inequality

I was reading an old paper in french where the authors claim that the following "obvious and natural inequality" holds. If $a_1,\ldots,a_n>0$ are all positive numbers, then
$$\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} a_j\leq \left(\, \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a_j} \right)^{n-1}\left(\, \prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}  a_k\right).$$
I managed to prove this by induction, but I'm not satisfied at all by that approach. Is there a nice way to prove this directly? (using basic inequalities, or some convexity argument for example). Also, is there any reason for this inequality to be really "obvious" or "natural"?

Comment: It is a version of **Sierpinski inequality**. See this [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4443889/305862)

Answer (score -1):

Note that the asserted inequality is equivalent to
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n \prod_{\substack{1\le k\le n\\k\ne j}} \frac1{a_k} \le \biggl( \sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a_j} \biggr)^{n-1};
$$
but this is indeed "obvious" because the right-hand side, when expanded out, becomes a sum of $n^{n-1}$ positive terms, $n$ of which are the ones on the left-hand side. (Indeed each summand on the left appears multiple times in the expanded version of the right, so one could even improve the inequality by a factor like $(n-1)!$.)

Comment: See my comment above.